# How to use static analysis collector plugin in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, static-analysis, pmd

I am new to jenkins, I have installed https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Analysis+Collector+Plugin and restarted jenkins. I dont find any place for the plugin configuration.

Can someone help on guiding to the configuration location of the analysis collector plugin

Comment: The "Static Analysis Collector" plugin is deprecated in favor of "Warnings Next Generation".

https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/

Answer (score 0):

As plugin Page clearly stats that

> **This plug-in is an add-on for the plug-ins Checkstyle, Dry, FindBugs, PMD, Task Scanner, and Warnings:** the plug-in collects the
>   different analysis results and shows the results in a combined trend
>   graph. Additionally, the plug-in provides health reporting and build
>   stability based on these combined results.

This plugin will work on top the other analysis plugin.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Static+Code+Analysis+Plug-ins

[image]

You need not to make any specific changes in your job apart from using static code analyzer plugins.

It also provides you additional portlets as well